# Express doesn't set 'set-cookies' header only on localhost

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am developing  a little web app where i wanted to set cookies from the server side with express.
I'm using firebase functions, express and CookieParser.
When i deploy my project into firebase cloud works perfectly, but when i serve from my computer 'Set-cookies' doesn't appear in the header and there are no cookies store.
Why is this happening?

node-v8.11.2

```
app.use(cookieParser());    
app.get('/cookie',(req,res)=>{
   res.cookie("test","This is a test");  
   res.end('test');
});
```

**EDIT:**
I fix it by setting cache control to private.

```
app.get('/cookie',(req,res)=>{
   res.setHeader('Cache-Control','private');
   res.cookie("test","This is a test");  
   res.end('test');
});
```

Comment: One difference that comes to mind is localhost is probably http, whereas hosted firebase will be https.

Comment: @Jason any idea to solve this while serving in local?

Comment: Can you try setting httpOnly and or domain in the cookie options?

Comment: @Jason I’ve already try it... still not working

Comment: I copy/pasted your code locally and ran it - worked as expected. How are you calling this endpoint? Are you using the Fetch API?

Comment: @Jason did you run it as a firebase funciton? If you did, which version of node Js are you using?

Comment: I found out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session/44935288) which solve my problm.