# Firebase Cookie Limitation

Tags: html, firebase, cookies, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase hosting and functions(along with authentication and database) for my web application and I've come across [this restriction only allowing the cookie name "__session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session).

I was wondering if this would be a cause for concern if I were to build a full scale application with the firebase platform. From my experiences, the firebase team doesn't seem to have plans to allow for additional cookie names in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

As of this answer entry 3/18/2021, GCP Firebase functions and/or hosting still does not support HTTP/S cookie names other than `__session` as stated in the official like documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies and confirmed by my recent and slightly inconvenienced programming development work trying to use that platform.

It does not seem like a technical limitation as much as an optimization, both as for Google product and for cloud computing, meaning that it probably won't be changed anytime soon still.