# How to use multiple cookies in Firebase hosting + Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase, session-cookies, firebase-hosting, express-session, google-cloud-run

My app was fully hosted in cloud run and i was happy with that (except cloud run throws some statx container sandbox limitation errors).

Recently I moved the static files to **firebase hosting and route api requests to cloud run** (It seems awesome combo for me).

But some of my api routes (pointing to cloud run) uses cookies so I ran into another issue that firebase removes the cookies for cloud run routes.

Firebase hosting removes cookies. Is there any way to use my custom cookie for cloud run routes. I don't want cookies for static assets but need for **cloud run requests**.

---

## Update:

I have read the another [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session) that firebase hosting strips all cookies other than a ***__session*** cookie, that's the only cookie it supports.

> There is no way to use custom or multiple cookies in firebase
>   hosting  ‍♂️

In my use case the app authentication uses a cookie variable and after authentication session (session also set cookies, so multiple cookies are there) will set.

**What I have tried:** In order to work session cookies, I have changed session cookie name to __session so both uses __session.

The problem is session no longer works. Because when I check request headers, multiple __session cookies set like the following,

```
Cookie: __session=auth_1234 __session=s%jashd3yq4kqj-sd43.jasyd7346%asdkjh4%asdkhk3j4h
```

Is there any way to overwrite previous **__session** cookie?

Because session cookie is set automatically by express session, right?

Comment: The duplicate link is for Cloud Functions, but the same logic would apply for Cloud Run.

Comment: @DougStevenson I already read that but I would like to know there is an option to store custom cookies other than __session, or how can I store multiple cookies? Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer there clearly says there is no alternative - "we strip all cookies from the request other than __session".

Comment: I have edited my question, that's the use case of my app. Firebase hosting may not be suitable for my use case.

Comment: The question has already been marked as a duplicate, which means it can't accept new answers.  If you have a new question, you should post it separately.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was not aware of that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Wow. I just spent 5 days reading every single line (and rewriting it in my own notes) of the Firebase docs only to come across this total deal-breaker tucked away that's not even highlighted as important! https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies - this is why I obsess over reading cloud services docs before I write any code.