# Firebase App with Cloud functions Cookie not being set on firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, httpcookie

Have a firebase app (server side React) that receives a http only cookie from a firebase functions Rest API as part of the response. This works fine on localhost but when i publish to firebase hosting no cookie is received. I'm thinking its either because the FB hosting is https or it is CORS related that the cookie is not being set.
Insight and how to fix would be helpful.
Cheers

Comment: Hi @JGC, please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session) and see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Yes the thread did answer the question. Looks like firebase hosting strips all but session cookies. Thanks