# nuxtServerInit not receiving cookies

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

### What I am trying to achieve

The basic idea is to *send a user to another route when a cookie is received* in the Nuxt router middleware.

The middleware is always called both on server-side and client-side, and it works perfectly in the dev environment.

**The problem that happens only in production is that the server-side middleware never receives the cookie.**

---

### My attempt

The logic is simple: `nuxtServerInit` is called on the server [before](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/) the router middleware is called. So it gets the cookie from the user and saves it in Vuex:

```js
nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {
  const token = this.$cookies.get('test');
  commit('auth/setToken', { value: !!token}) }
}
```

Then, the router middleware is called and checks Vuex if the cookie is there to redirect the user:

```js
export default function ({ store, route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path === '/' && store.getters['auth/getToken']) { redirect('/test'); }
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine locally, but upon deployment no redirection happens.
**What am I missing?**

---

### More info

As that may be relevant, I am using a firebase cloud function to host my Nuxt ssr website:

```js
exports.renderApp = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
  await nuxt.ready(); nuxt.render(req, res);
});
```

I first thought it may be a cookie problem, but I tried setting them up with vanilla js, then (as implemented above) I tried [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt), as well as bypassing Vuex completely and checking the `req.headers.cookie` directly in the middleware. The result is always the same: works in dev, does not work in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the name of your cookie to `__session`.

You can find more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session).

Comment: Yes, it works in production! Thank you very much, @Łukasz.
That firebase issue should be better documented, it currently is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies