# Vite Production Build on Firebase doesn't send cookies in request, unlike development build

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

There's a strange behavior happening on Firebase when I try to make requests containing cookies from the frontend to the backend (different domains).

This only happens when deployed on firebase. I'm debugging on my side, but I don't understand by the cookie isn't attached to the request in production, but is attached in dev mode:
[image: Running on firebase]

[image: Running locally]

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @FrankVanPuffelen's comment, I've implemented the necessary mechanisms. But the problem still persists, because for some reason the domain name differs from environment to environment.

These are my cookies when I run it locally:
[image]
[image]
And here when I run it remotely, the domain differs between requests, I wonder if it matters...:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would this explain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929653/firebase-cloud-function-wont-store-cookie-named-other-than-session?

Comment: Added a few more screenshots after checking out the post